How do I extend or override UserManager.FindByEmail() to have it return only what I want?
My login method is below and you'll see I have to call my user again after I fetch it with _userManager.FindByEmailAsync() because there are a couple of fields Points and Tokens that are calculated as a Sum()
Question - Is there any way I can extend _userManager.FindByEmailAsync() so that it will run the Sum as I do in the .Select() call, so I don't have a redundant call to the DB?
I tried to call:
var userFromRepo = await _userManager.Users.Select(p => new Core.Entities.User { Id = p.Id, Email = p.Email, UserName = p.UserName}).SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Email == loginDto.Email);

and pass it into CheckPasswordSignInAsync() but the result failed, so it's looking for something other than Email, UserName, or Id. But what?
If I just call this to return the whole User:
var userFromRepo = await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Email == loginDto.Email);

It works but I can't run the Sum() calls for Point and Token
I also tried extending UserManager like this, with no luck.


public static User FindByEmail(this UserManager <User> input, string email) {
  return input.Users.Select(p => new User {
    Id = p.Id,
      Email = p.Email,
      UserName = p.UserName
  }).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);
}



Here is my login method.


[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto loginDto) {
  
  var userFromRepo = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDto.Email);

  if (userFromRepo == null) return Unauthorized(new ApiResponse(401));

  if (userFromRepo.IsActive == false) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404, "This account is no longer active."));

  var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(userFromRepo, loginDto.Password, false);

  if (!result.Succeeded) return Unauthorized(new ApiResponse(401));

  var user = await _dbContext.Users
    .Select(p => new {
        Id = p.Id,
        Email = p.Email,
        UserName = p.UserName,
        Hosted = p.Hosted,
        Instructed = p.Instructed,
        Attended = p.Attended,
        IsBoarded = p.IsBoarded,
        IsActive = p.IsActive,
        Likers = p.LikersCount,
        Rating = p.Rating,
        YearStarted = p.YearStarted,
        YearsInstructing = p.YearsInstructing,
        YearsPracticing = System.DateTime.Now.Year - p.YearStarted,
        Certification = p.Certification.ToString(),
        CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
        PhotoUrl = p.IsBoarded ? p.UserPhoto : "assets/images/user.png",
        Age = p.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge(),
        DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
        ExperienceLevel = p.ExperienceLevel.GetEnumName(),
        Points = p.UserPoints.Sum(p => p.Points),
        Tokens = p.Tokens.Sum(p => p.Tokens),
        Token = _tokenService.CreateToken(userFromRepo, (from userRole in p.UserRoles join role in _dbContext.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id select role.Name).ToList()),
        IsInstructor = p.IsInstructor
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == userFromRepo.Id);

  if (user == null) return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404));

  return Ok(user);
}




I don't know enough to provide you with an answer but have you considered implementing a custom UserStore that inherits from the base one? You can then choose to override the methods you want and use .Include() for eager loading, and that SHOULD mean you query the database only once, and have the required data available at a more top level

Did you try inheriting UserManager class and overriding FindByEmail method? There you can always call base.FindByEmail base implementation. Here you have more details how to customize identity in ASP.NET

To solve my issue I just changed this code below. Now I only fetch once from the DB, instead of 3 times.
Maybe someone who knows UserManager can weigh in on the difference between what I had and what I have now in terms of security?
// Old Code
var userFromRepo = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDto.Email);  

// New code     
var user = await _userManager.Users
    .Include(p => p.TokensPoints)
    .Include(p => p.UserRoles)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == loginDto.Email);

next I just map the fields I want to the DTO being returned to the client.

If you want to extend the _userManager.FindByEmailAsync method, you need to create a custom class which inherts the IUserEmailStore, since the FindByEmailAsync method will call the IUserEmailStore's FindByEmailAsync method.
The source codes for the _userManager is like this:
public virtual async Task<TUser?> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    IUserEmailStore<TUser> store = GetEmailStore();
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Shared.ArgumentNullThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(email, "email");
    email = NormalizeEmail(email);
    TUser val = await store.FindByEmailAsync(email, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    if (val == null && Options.Stores.ProtectPersonalData)
    {
        ILookupProtectorKeyRing service = _services.GetService<ILookupProtectorKeyRing>();
        ILookupProtector protector = _services.GetService<ILookupProtector>();
        if (service != null && protector != null)
        {
            foreach (string allKeyId in service.GetAllKeyIds())
            {
                string normalizedEmail = protector.Protect(allKeyId, email);
                val = await store.FindByEmailAsync(normalizedEmail, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    return val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return val;
}

Inside the new implemented IUserEmailStore class ,you could modify the FindByEmailAsync like below:
_dbContext.Users
            .Where(u => u.Email == email)
            .Select(p => new UserDto
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Email = p.Email,
                UserName = p.UserName,
                Hosted = p.Hosted,
                Instructed = p.Instructed,
                Attended = p.Attended,
                IsBoarded = p.IsBoarded,
                IsActive = p.IsActive,
                Likers = p.LikersCount,
                Rating = p.Rating,
                YearStarted = p.YearStarted,
                YearsInstructing = p.YearsInstructing,
                YearsPracticing = DateTime.Now.Year - p.YearStarted,
                Certification = p.Certification.ToString(),
                CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
                PhotoUrl = p.IsBoarded ? p.UserPhoto : "assets/images/user.png",
                Age = p.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge(),
                DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                ExperienceLevel = p.ExperienceLevel.GetEnumName(),
                Points = p.UserPoints.Sum(up => up.Points),
                Tokens = p.Tokens.Sum(t => t.Tokens),
                Token = _tokenService.CreateToken(p, 
                    (from userRole in p.UserRoles
                     join role in _dbContext.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                     select role.Name).ToList()),
                IsInstructor = p.IsInstructor
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Then register it inside the program.cs:
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserEmailStore>();

More details about how to use it, you could refer to this article.

do you think you could show a more complete example of what that method would look like?

You do not have to call the user again the user already exist on userfromrepo.
Just preform your logic on your current user object, userfromrepo.column name = what ever value. It will not update the database. Just the current user object and return it.

The OP was asking about extending and/or overriding UserManger to fetch child entities.
